# AWS logging separate log files using SLF4J

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, logging, slf4j

Has anyone implemented using log **SLF4J** to enable the application separate the files by tenant on Amazon environment?

I made this implementation in my application, running on *tomcat* in localhost site, the log files are generated normally, but when I deploy on Amazon and then I download the logs, files are not generated, the outputs end up going to the `catalina.out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem setting the path that matches the structure that the logs are stored in tomcat Amazon.

I made the following change in my filter configuration file.

```
<File>/var/log/tomcat8/nomedoarquivo.log</File>
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html